# How can I write VBA code to disable modern comments in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) code be written in a macro to take the tick out of “Enable modern comments “

I have thousands of documents that contain hyperlinks that do not work with modern comments

I know this can be turned off manually but I would like a macro to do this

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? Your tags say **VBA**, **wordpress** and **VB6** which are complete different and unrelated things. If you mean VBA: Which program are you talking about? Word? Excel? Powerpoint? Visio? MsProject? Any 3rd party program that licensed VBA?

Comment: Also vb6 and the modern version of Visual Basic (vb.net) are different languages so please say precisely what you mean.

Comment: This is for word.  I couldn’t get tags to work properly

Comment: AFAIK, the option for modern comments is not in the Object Model and not subject to vba manipulation.